# How to install CVX in Python, along with chompack in windows 64 bit?

Tags: python, cvxopt, cvx

Can anyone please give me the links to download the links to  install CVX in Phyton, along with chompack? I tried several version but never able to install chompack. I get error message like "failed building wheel CVXOPT" while installing chompack. But no error message in installing cvxopt. My machine windows 64 bit.